# Converting a theme part from Tlc to Python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.11, tlc

I have a problem I'm having, which I don't know how to solve, due to my lack of knowledge. I'm trying to recreate the vertical scrollbar of the "[Azure-ttk-theme](https://github.com/rdbende/Azure-ttk-theme/blob/main/theme/dark.tcl)" theme (given that the program will not be for commercial use, but for personal use). To help me out, I used "[plastik_theme.py](https://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/ttk-gsoc/samples/plastik_theme.py)", and was mostly successful in translating it from Tcl to Python. There remains one last part to do, which I can't translate, because I can't find the same or similar examples around:

```
ttk::style element create Vertical.Scrollbar.thumb \
            image [list $I(vert-accent) \
                disabled  $I(vert-basic) \
                pressed $I(vert-hover) \
                active $I(vert-hover) \
            ] -sticky ns
```

How should I write it in Python? Unfortunately, I haven't found anything around, even converters or similar. I have no desire to use the theme in question, just for scrollbar use, so what should I do? Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an example of creating an element in the official [tkinter documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#ttk-styling). Search that page for `element_create`.

You will need to download the image files, create the images, and then create the element like this:

```
vert_accent_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="vert-accent.png")
vert_basic_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="vert-basic.png")
vert_hover_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="vert-hover.png")

style = ttk.Style(root)
style.element_create(
    "Vertical.Scrollbar.thumb", "image",
    vert_accent_image,
    ("disabled", vert_basic_image),
    ("pressed", vert_hover_image),
    ("active", vert_hover_image),
    sticky="ns"
)
```

Make sure you keep a reference to the images, and of course adjust the filenames to point to wherever the images are.